# Event listeners (onkeypress, onkeydown) on input not working in Android numeric keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, input, dom-events

I don't know why, but after hours spent dealing with this I can say there's something wrong.

I have a simple input

```
<input type="number">
```

I want it to accept **only** numbers (digit [0-9]) and nothing more. In order to achieve this I added an event listener where I control the keycode of the event.

Nothing special and everything working on almost all platforms, problems comes with Android. Here the

> type="number"

causes numeric keyboard to appear - and that's great - with also some other characters (comma, dot, hyphen...). When you press one of this special characters the behavior is strange:

- onkeypress event: absolutely **not firing** (why???)
- onkeydown event: the event is firing and the relative function is called. The problem is that the browser **has already typed the character** (why??) so is not possible to call the "preventDefault" function of "event".
- on input event: the event is firing but "code" and "which" properties of "event" object are undefined. Moreover, like before, the browser **has already typed the character**.

What am I missing?

My environment is powerd by AngularJs so I setted up event listeners inside a directive. However doing same things with jQuery doesn't solve problems.

Someone can suggest to use a "$parsers" to push my custom value without unwanted characters. Anyway this doesn't work I guess because the type of the input is "number" and it expect only numbers (another way to say the browser on Android is doing something wrong..)

Here there's a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hb3u9bc/), open it on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this directive with `$parsers.unshift`:

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', '$window', function($filter, $window) {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

      if (!ctrl) return;

      scope.plainNumber = scope.test+'';

      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {         

      if(!viewValue){
         viewValue = scope.plainNumber;
      }
        scope.plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

        elem.val(scope.plainNumber);
        return scope.plainNumber;            
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

And usage:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="test" format />
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0n78cb4/)</kbd>

---

*Tested on Android*

Comment: It's not perfect but I think this is the best possible option, thanks you

Answer (score 7):

The `keypress` event isn't fired, only `keydown` and `keyup`. `onkeydown` you're able to invoke the `preventDefault()` method. But what to prevent? `charCode` is always `0` and `keyCode` is `229`. You should check all the input.

Something like this:

```
if(!event.charCode) {
    this.removeInvalidChar();
    return;
}

private removeInvalidChar(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let input = this.control.control.value;

        if (input) {
            input.split('').forEach((char: string) => {
                if (!this.pattern.test(char)) {
                    input = input.replace(char, '');
                }
            });
            this.control.control.setValue(input);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "The keypress event isn't fired", Actually this is the real problem! Why isn't fired? It's not normal.. Moreover, your code won't work because on keydown event the char is already inside the input field (you can remove it but you'll get an ugly effect). Please try it with the Fiddle on Android

Comment: Well, I use it onkeyup...And yes, the result isn't ideal...You can see flickering when the invalid input is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

use inputType="numberSigned" it will provide you only numbers between 0-9 , atleast in native android it works flawlessly.